# Laravel 5.4 array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array error while using components forms

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

It gives me this error, when I use large forms instead of html forms,

settings.blade.php;

```
 @if (is_array($settings) || is_object($settings))

   @foreach($settings as $set)

      {{ Form::bstext('title', $set->title )}} 
         .
         .
         .
    @endforeach

 @endif
```

FormServiceProvider.php

```
 Form::component('bstext', 'components.form.text', ['name', 'value', 'attributes']);
```

and text.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{$name}}</label>
    {{ Form::text($name, $value, array_merge(['class' => 'form-control'], $attributes)) }}
</div>
</div>
```

Where do i mistake ?

Comment: So `$attributes` is not an array, as you didn't provide initial value for it.

Comment: is it neccesary ? even if how can i do that ? (i'm beginner)

Answer (score 1):

i edited my formserviceprovider and it works.

```
Form::component('input_form', 'components.form.input', ['name', 'value', 'attributes'=>[]]);
```

thanks for @u_mulder